# Stripe creditcard elements not loaded in Safari browser

Tags: stripe-payments

We use stripe v.3 to add creditcard for a customer. It works on all browsers chrome and firefox. But safari returns the following error.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: elements

Tested on physical iphone device it seems older version cant create the stripe elements leaving the input field, clumpy and not showing the CC information. Check screenshot.

The bug occurs on iOS version 11.3.1 and down. The iframe is showing in the source elements but dont add the class .StripeElement to the dom.

[image: screenshot]

```js
import {
  Component,
  Inject,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  OnDestroy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

import { PaymentService } from '@services/http/payment.service';
import { StateService } from '@services/Logic/state.service';

import { TranslatePipe } from '@app/pipes/translate.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-credit-card-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'addCreditCard.html',
  styleUrls: ['addCreditCard.scss', '../../dialogs.scss'],
})
export class AddCreditCardDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('cardInfo', { static: true }) cardInfo: ElementRef;
  card: any;
  cardHandler = this.onChange.bind(this);
  error: string;
  cardholderName: string;

  constructor(
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private translatePipe: TranslatePipe,
    private stateService: StateService,
    private paymentService: PaymentService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddCreditCardDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.card = elements.create('card');
    this.card.mount(this.cardInfo.nativeElement);

    this.card.addEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
    // Force the Element frame to paint once it is visible on the page
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.forceReflow('.StripeElement');
    }, 1000);

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.card.removeEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
    this.card.destroy();
  }

  forceReflow(selector) {
    const el = document.querySelector(selector);

    if (el) {
      const initialDisplay = el.style.display;

      el.style.display = 'none';
      el.offsetHeight;
      el.style.display = initialDisplay;
    }
  }



  onChange({ error }) {
    if (error) {
      this.error = error.message;
    } else {
      this.error = null;
    }

    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  async onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (!this.cardholderName || this.cardholderName.length === 0) {
      return this.toastr.error(this.translatePipe.transform('TOAST_MESSAGES.ERROR.MISSING_CARDHOLDER'));
    }

    this.stateService.toggleWaitingPage(true);

    // create a Setup Intent for this card
    const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.handleCardSetup(
      this.data.client_secret,
      this.card,
      {
        payment_method_data: {
          billing_details: { name: this.cardholderName },
        },
      }
    );

    if (error) {
      this.toastr.error(error.message);
      this.stateService.toggleWaitingPage(false);
    } else {
      // create a Payment Method from the previously created Setup Intent and attach it to the Customer
      const paymentMethod = await this.paymentService
        .attachPaymentMethod({ payment_method: setupIntent.payment_method })
        .toPromise();

      this.close(paymentMethod);
    }
  }

  close(data: any = null): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(data);
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;

  .form-row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 40px;

    #card-errors {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #f82e42;
    }
  }
}

p {
  color: #707070;
}
.input_area{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 115px;
}
.body_area{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  .attention{
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    background-color: #F6F9FC;
    .notranslate {
      color: #89b153;
      font-size: 18px;
      margin-left: 8px;
      padding-top: 2px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
    p{
      text-align: left !important;
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    .notranslate{
      color: #707070;
      place-self: center;
    }
  }
}

.header_wrapper{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  .pinpay{
    margin-bottom: unset !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #4a4a56;
  }
  .img {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    border-radius: 500px;
    @media (max-width: 320px) and (max-height: 438px) { display: none; }
    .image-icon{
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      margin-top: 3px;
      margin-left: 8.4px;
    }
  }
}

#cardholder-name {
  width: 95%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog_container">
  <div class="header_row">
    <div class="header_left"></div>
    <span class="close" (click)="close()">✕</span>
    <h5 id="header_title">{{ 'DIALOGS.ADD_CREDIT_CARD.TITLE' | translate }}</h5>
  </div>


  <div class="header_wrapper">
    <div class="img">
   
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; margin-bottom: unset">
      <p class="pinpay">PinployPay</p>
      <span></span>™
    </div>
    <p class="pinpay1">Sikker handel</p>
 </div>
  <div class="body_area">
    <div class="attention">
      <mat-icon [matTooltip]="'PAGES.SETTINGS.PROFILE.COMPLETION_RATE_INFO' | translate">info</mat-icon>
      <p>{{ 'DIALOGS.ADD_CREDIT_CARD.MESSAGE' | translate }}</p>
    </div>

    <p>
      <mat-icon class="notranslate">remove_shopping_cart</mat-icon>{{
      'DIALOGS.ADD_CREDIT_CARD.MESSAGE_1' | translate }}
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="input_area">
    <input
      id="cardholder-name"
      [(ngModel)]="cardholderName"
      [placeholder]="'DIALOGS.ADD_CREDIT_CARD.CARDHOLDER' | translate"
    />

    <form #checkout="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(checkout)" class="checkout">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div id="card-info" #cardInfo></div>
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert" *ngIf="error">{{ error }}</div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="pinploy_button_v2_mobile_green">Ok</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.html

```html
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>

    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script>
      const stripeKey =
        window.location.origin === "https://www.pinploy.com"
          ? "pk_live_******q"
          : "pk_test_1P******";
      let stripe = Stripe(stripeKey);
      let elements = stripe.elements();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share the exact code you're using.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I posted the code below thanks